# Select in SSMS Fails to Return Expected Row

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Given a table MyTable with a column MyCol defined as NVARCHAR(Max), the first SELECT returns one row in SSMS as expected while the second select returns no rows.

```
DECLARE @code NVarChar='ABC'

SELECT * FROM MyTable q WHERE MyCol = 'ABC'
SELECT * FROM MyTable q WHERE MyCol = @code
```

using ADO.Net to populate the parameter @code and execute the query also returns one row, as expected.

Why does the second SELECT return no rows when executed in SSMS?

Comment: Debugging 101: `SELECT @code;` Also please read https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have no length on the definition of the variable.  Use:

```
DECLARE @code NVarChar(255) = N'ABC';
```

Or some length.  The default length for `declare` is 1.

Comment: And no error message trying to assign a string that is too long... Fun stuff.

Comment: And if it's `NVARCHAR` it should have an `N` prefix.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . Won't it convert it to unicode, even without the `N`?

Comment: No, you could lose data. Consider cases where the string isn't a simple `ABC`: `DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(255) = 'ыайж'; SELECT @x;`